# Tkd widget not finding row and column options

Tags: d, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create a simple GUI application using `tkd` package and following code:

```
// modified from: https://github.com/nomad-software/tkd

import tkd.tkdapplication; 

class Application : TkdApplication    {                
    auto labellist = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", ]; 
    override protected void initInterface() {         
        int ncol =0; 
        auto frame = new Frame(2, ReliefStyle.groove); 
        frame.pack(10);  
        foreach(lab; labellist){
            auto label = new Label(frame, lab);
            label.grid(row=nrow, column=0);
            auto entry = new Entry(frame); 
            entry.grid(row=nrow, column=1);
            nrow += 1; 
        }
        auto exitButton = new Button(frame, "Exit").setCommand(&this.exitCommand).pack(10);                                  
    }
    private void exitCommand(CommandArgs args)  { 
        this.exit();                                 
    }
}

void main(string[] args){
    auto app = new Application(); 
    app.run(); 
}
```

However, it is giving following error:

```
$ dub run
Performing "debug" build using /usr/bin/dmd for x86_64.
x11 1.0.21: target for configuration "tcltk-import" is up to date.
tcltk 8.6.5: target for configuration "library" is up to date.
tkd 1.1.12: target for configuration "library" is up to date.
tkdgui ~master: building configuration "application"...
source/app.d(15,15): Error: undefined identifier row
source/app.d(15,25): Error: undefined identifier column
source/app.d(17,15): Error: undefined identifier row
source/app.d(17,25): Error: undefined identifier column
source/app.d(18,4): Error: undefined identifier nrow
/usr/bin/dmd failed with exit code 1.
```

Details about grid are mentioned [here](https://tkd.dpldocs.info/tkd.widget.widget.Widget.grid.html). Row and column are valid options to be entered.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code. Here's the first:

```
label.grid(row=nrow, column=0);
           ^^^^      ^^^^^^^
```

D does not support named parameters, which you're attempting to use. Instead you will need to use positional parameters:

```
label.grid(0, nrow);
```

FWIW, there are some proposals to add named parameters to D, but none are in the language as of now.

The second issue is `nrow` is not defined anywhere. Judging by the existence of `ncol` and the fact it's used nowhere, it seems you changed the code from dealing with columns to dealing with rows and did not change the name of `ncol` to `nrow`.